# Portable phantom power

Tags: phantom, power, field-recording

Does anybody know of a reasonably inexpensive portable (i.e. battery powered) phantom power supply?  Most of the ones I've seen are in the $150-$200 range.  Or is that in itself inexpensive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behringer do some inexpensive ones. I realise many people frown at Behringer but its a battery pack, how can it go so wrong? :)

Behringer PS400

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is the quality of this pack you are buying because cheaper may not necessarily be better.

The money you saved on buying a cheap battery pack could never buy back your reputation lost if you were to turn to the director and say "Sorry, can I have that scene played one more time? My mic ran out of juice or malfunctioned."

Comment: very true, but for that price you could probably get 2 and keep one as a back up? If it's a worry you could try looking at the ARTAccessories phantom I and phantom II, I've not used them but I have other ART products and they are made extremely well.

Comment: A mic is going to draw as much current as a mic is gonna draw. A battery pack is a battery pack.

Comment:  @Shaun. A car is a car. It gets you from point A to point B. So what's the difference between a Pinto and a Corvette? (no offense to anyone who drives one.) They're the same, right? They get you from point A to point B. A car is a car....... I'm just saying I wouldn't trust the cheapest battery pack out there unless it is a tried and true rugged piece of equipment that holds out in cold temperatures, lasts long and stays lasting long and doesn't shut off in the heat of filming a movie. I'm speaking from experience from using a cheaper brand of power supply and it cutting out and breaking 

Comment: completely, only for my studio technician to tell me it was a poor soldering job on the connections and poor layout of the circuitry that made it prone to break and not stay solid during regular production conditions.

Comment: @utopia - build your own then...they're not hard ;)

Comment: @Shaun not a bad idea! lol But, my take on battery-powered-equipment, is that if you shoot 10 hours a day everyday day like most people, the amount of money you will spend on batteries alone will pay for that piece of equipment you just bought in like 2 weeks maybe.